# How to use ExcelServices in Sharepoint?

Tags: site, excel-services, secure-store

I want to use the Excel workbook in my SharePoint using ExcelServices.

I have done all settings in "Excel Services Applications" & "Secure Store Service" in "Manage Service Application" option of "Central Admin".

But I am not getting "ExcelService" option in the Save to SharePoint Dialogbox of Save & Share in Excel-2010. And I am not able to save that Excel file to my Document Library, whose path is saved in Trusted Location.

Also in Excel-2007, I am getting same problem not able to save the file on the Site.

Everytime I am getting this error in 2007 & 2010.
"...... path does not exist. Check the path and try again".

What to do to publish this file on SharePoint site, and use the data in my site.

Comment: In the Site Collection itself, have you checked that the `SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features` feature is activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plz refer below link.

http://manojvnair.blogspot.in/2011/05/issue-with-save-to-sharepoint-in-excel.html

Hotpe it helps... :D

Comment: Thanks Chandegara. It works for me. Now I am able to publish my Excel file to SharePoint site. But when I open the Excel file from DocumentLibrary, every time I am getting this error.
 "The workbook cannot be opened because it contains the following features that are not supported by Excel in the browser:" 


• Workbook sharing


Would you like to try and open this file in Excel?